# How to auto update data in react

Tags: reactjs, django, react-hooks, axios, state

Using react, I want to update chart data every 2 seconds from Django database
but each 2 seconds charts component keeps recreating.
how to prevent that from happening?

In zoneActions.js :

```
export const getZonesList = (cname) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: ZONE_LIST_REQUEST });
    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/zones/get/${cname}/`,
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: ZONE_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ZONE_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.detail
          ? error.response.data.detail
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

dashboard.js :

```
  const { cname } = useParams();
  const zoneList = useSelector((state) => state.zoneList);
  const { zones } = zoneList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getZonesList(cname));
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(getZonesList(cname));
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [dispatch]);
```